# How is NodeJS notified of resolved Promises?

Tags: node.js

I've read the NodeJS documentation in regard to the event loop:
https://nodejs.dev/learn/the-nodejs-event-loop

I understand that functions like an API call or setTimeout have their own threads that resolve them, but how is NodeJS then notified of that resolve to place a setTimeout callback in the message queue, or a promise callback back in the call stack?

Is Node checking its job queue after each function execution in the call stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Highly simplified...

Imagine that there's an array of resolved promises. Every time a promise resolves, it gets pushed on this array.

When no code is running, node checks this array and runs all the associated callbacks.

Comment: Does node itself push the resolved promise into that "array"? Isn't it preoccupied with the main call stack? Or is there some sort of other connection open between node and the API?

Comment: Node doesn't really have to. The *thing* that resolves the promise (such a an operation completing) can register the callback. The line is a bit blurry what node and V8 does.

Ultimately that triggers this is the callback that's passed into the 1st constructor argument of `new Promise()`. The reality is a bit more involved, but this is a good enough approximation.

Comment: So in short, the first argument to `new Promise` is a callback. When it's called, a microtask is scheduled for the next iteration of the loop.